# how to prevent <mark> background overlapping other text

Tags: html, css, sass

i need to create a text withs some markings that need to look a bit customized ( using an image )
i used the background-property and padding like so:

```
mark{
    padding:10px;
    background:url(http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300);  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

which works as planned, but the backgroundimage is obscuring the previous text-line.
adding a z-index also did not work.
see fiddle:
[fiddlelyfidd](https://jsfiddle.net/vy0tgw81/1/)

any ideas on how to send it to the back?

thanks

Comment: Its not  universal solution but in you case its helps. Just add the background-position: 0px 10px;

Comment: kindly check with @AlisherGafurov solution it's working fine. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vy0tgw81/3/

Answer (score 1):

try to add `background-position: 0px 10px;` it's working fine

```
   mark{
        z-index:-10;
        padding:10px;
        background:url(http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300);  
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: 0px 10px;

    }
```

[check this updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy0tgw81/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css declaration `background-clip: content-box`.

Moreover, `padding` and `z-index` may be useless.
Please see below.

```css
body{
  background-color:#666666;
  color:white;
}


mark{
  /*z-index:-10;*/
  /*padding:10px;*/
  background:url('http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<p>
“Higher up now we mark the gony, or gray albatross, anomalously so called, an unsightly, <mark>unpoetic bird, unlike its storied kinsman, which is the snow-white ghost</mark> of the haunted Capes of Hope and Horn.”

Excerpt From: Melville, Herman. “Billy Budd and Other Stories.” iBooks. 
</p>
```

Comment: However, please see also the [CSS background Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp). You might be interested to use other declarations as `background-size: contain`. I hope I was of any help.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i should have mentioned, that i do want the background of the <mark> to overlap with the text above it, but it has to be "under" the text. ( like an unprecise textwarker in the "real" world might )

Comment: It is not just that you see in the snippet? I see the image background behind the text.

Comment: yes. but i meant behind the first line of text when it is bigger then just "contain"